# If $Z = 1$, $Y$ is Rademacher, $W \sim N(0, 1)$, and $X = WY$, is $X$ conditionally independent of $Y$ given $Z$?

Tags: probability, independence

Suppose $X, Y, Z, W$ are random variables. If $Z = 1$, $Y$ is Rademacher, $W \sim N(0, 1)$, and $X = WY$, is $X$ conditionally independent of $Y$ given $Z$, i.e., $f(x, y|z) = f(x|z)f(y|z)$? Here, $f$ denotes the pdf.

This is a question I had after reading one of the answers to this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338612/if-x-perp-yz-does-this-mean-that-x-perp-yz-w-how-about-the-other-way). I'm not quite sure why knowing $Z = 1$ would make $X$ independent of $Y$.

Comment: $\sigma(Z)$ is trivial and does not bring any information. Conditioning on a constant random variable is like not conditioning at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are conditioning on constant, you just need to show $X$ and $Y$ are independent. By the symmetry of the standard normal distribution:

$$P(X \leq a)=P(WY \leq a)=0.5P(-W\leq a)+0.5P(W\leq a)=P(W \leq a)$$

Hence

$$P(X \leq a, Y =c)=P(WY \leq a, Y =c)=P(W\leq a, Y=c)=P(W \leq a)P(Y=c)$$

so that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Did you mean to write $P(WY \leq a) = 0.5P(W \leq a) + 0.5P(-W \leq a)$?

Comment: @Adrian Yes; corrected.